# Zip in python path not working as expected

Tags: python

I have the `msgpack` module in a zip file called `msgpack.zip`.

When I add the zip file to the python path, I'm able to import the module, but not the compiled parts of it:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.insert(0, 'msgpack.egg')
>>> import msgpack
>>> from msgpack._packer import Packer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'msgpack._packer'
>>>
```

**However**, if I extract the zip file to the same directory I'm in, then it works:

Verification that I don't have `msgpack` installed through some other means...

```
cmadrigal-MBP:tmp caleb.madrigal$ ls
msgpack   msgpack.zip

cmadrigal-MBP:tmp caleb.madrigal$ python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 20 2015, 11:10:55)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import msgpack
>>> from msgpack._packer import Packer
>>>
```

Note that I do NOT have `msgpack` to any other path on my computer. If I remove the `msgpack` folder from the directory I'm working in, I get an import error on `import msgpack`.

**So the question is, why does importing a module contained in a zip not import the compiled parts of the library, but they are imported if I extract the zip to a directory and then try importing it?**

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PkgResources#resource-extraction)

> If the resource is in an archive distribution (such as a zipped egg),
>   it will be extracted to a cache directory

The default cache directory is determined by the function `get_default_cache()`. The [doc](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PkgResources#platform-utilities) says

> Determine the default cache location for extracting resources from
>   zipped eggs. This routine returns the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment
>   variable, if set. Otherwise, on Windows, it returns a "Python-Eggs"
>   subdirectory of the user's "Application Data" directory. On all other
>   systems, it returns os.path.expanduser("~/.python-eggs") if
>   PYTHON_EGG_CACHE is not set.

So, my guess is that you have some issue with your `eggs` cache folder.

Comment: The documentation you pointed to looks like it has something to do with `setuptools`. But I'm not installing `msgpack` via pip. I compiled `msgpack` myself, and put it into a zip file. So I don't think it's got anything to do with an eggs cache.

Comment: I've done a trace of python's process with the strace. It behaviors as described. It's up to you now to check this or not.